# Is JSON optional?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

Based on my own understanding, JSON is somewhat like the parse function for Java. It parses the data to convert it to something that I don't understand. Currently I made a login function with the help of AJAX and JavaScript/jQuery. Originally I had the problem of it not working until someone points it out that the problem is that I set the dataType to JSON.
Should I learn JSON for a better data processing? And when and where should I use JSON?

Comment: Showing some not working codes might helpful.

Comment: Json isnt required for ajax login etc, but definitely learn it.

Comment: JSON makes life easy. If you understand objects and Array you understand JSON better. JSON is Javascript object notation.

Comment: JSON is a *data format* similar to XML, YAML or CSV. Many languages have built-in support for it which makes it convenient to use.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ the code is working what I'm trying to ask if JSOn is optional or required and what is it realy.

Comment: It's a data serialization method. It simply flattens the structure to parsable string. If you want to transfer or save structured data in string format you can use any of the serialization methods like JSON, XML, YAML etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format. It is easy for humans to read and write. It is easy for machines to parse and generate. It is based on a subset of the JavaScript Programming Language, Standard ECMA-262 3rd Edition - December 1999. JSON is a text format that is completely language independent

If you wan't to learn JSON,The article [Introducing JSON](http://www.json.org/index.html)  will help you

Answer (score 1):

JOSN is a plain text dataset encapsulated in the form of Key & Value pairs. It's flexible and error free. It's not a parser at all, it's just a standard way of passing data between two different parties. There are different JSON parsers available based on the platform/programming language you use to convert the JSON data into native objects.